# Как сделать include внешнего файла html в html страницу с помощью javascript?

Tags: html, javascript

Тот кто будет подключать внешний файл - не знает php и других языков программирования, так что, в идеале, я должна ему просто дать код, а он его у себя на странице просто вставить. Или такое можно сделать только с помощью фреймов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code.php -- страница с кодом. Может иметь любой формат.
Див result -- будет автоматически обновляться, без перезагрузки страницы, при изменении code.php

`<div id="result"></div>
     <script>
     function include_code() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "code.php",cache: false,success: function(html){
                $("#result").html(html);
            }
        });
     }
     $(document).ready(function(){
        include_code();setInterval('include_code()',1000);
     });
    </script>`

Comment: Это jQuery? :) Блин, надо всё же взяться поучить её, а то мало чего понятно. :) А без ajax-а и без библиотек - никак? :)

Comment: Если только фреймами, без кеширования.

Answer (score 1):

Во времена статики использовали [**SSI**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29)

К примеру,

Файл **index.html**:

```
<html>
    Hello 
    <!--#include virtual="foo.html"-->
</html>
```

Файл **foo.html**:

```
<html>
    World!
</html>
```